# Flutter Pubspec.yaml Warning: Publishable packages can't have git dependencies

Tags: git, flutter

I'm using Sembast Cloud Firestore type adapters in my pubspec.yaml:

```
  sembast_cloud_firestore_type_adapters:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/tekartik/sembast_flutter_more.dart
      path: cloud_firestore_type_adapters
      ref: dart2
      version: '>=0.1.0'
```

and loading adapters:

```
  loading:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/leonzone/loading.git
      path: loading
      ref: 8f5a63f
```

I got this error for both of the above lines:
`warning: Publishable packages can't have git dependencies.`

Here is my `flutter doctor`:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.24.0-7.0.pre.71, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2 darwin-x64,
    locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.50.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

My guess is that it helps you preventing publishing dummy/old package by doing extra check on package that are set to be published. You should add (at the root of the document, for example after the `version` field):

```
publish_to: none
```

to your `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: works but this needs to be added to the root yaml not individual dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Adding your SSH in git account will solve your problem. visit [Here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) to know how to generate SSH key

Comment: So this did not solve the specific error for me, the pubspec still makes the error. What it did do was resolve all the errors in the actual app, and I honestly have no clue how !

Comment: can you share your yaml file?

Comment: Well the app now runs now, thanks to your help. I could share it if you really want !